# How to fix TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm using below function to store predictions on target columns.

```
#define target and Id column
target = 'is_promoted'
IDcol = 'employee_id'

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score 

def modelfit(alg, dtrain, dtest, pred, target, IDcol, filename):
    alg.fit(dtrain[pred],dtrain[target])
    
    #predict training set
    dtrain_pred = alg.predict(dtrain[pred])
    
    #perform cross validation
    cv_score = cross_val_score(alg, dtrain[pred],dtrain[target],cv=20)
    cv_score = np.sqrt(np.abs(cv_score))
    
    print('\nmodel report')
    print(f1_score(dtrain[target],dtrain_pred))
    print("CV Score : Mean - %.4g | Std - %.4g | Min - %.4g | Max - %.4g" % (np.mean(cv_score),
                                                                             np.std(cv_score),
                                                                             np.min(cv_score),np.max(cv_score)))
    
    #predict on testing data                                                
    dtest[target] = alg.predict(dtest[pred])
    
                                                                             
    #export submission file                                
    IDcol.append(target)
    submission =pd.DataFrame({x: dtest[x] for x in IDcol})
    
    submission.to_csv(filename,index=False)
```

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
pred = [x for x in train.columns if x not in [target]+IDcol]

alg1=LogisticRegression()
modelfit(alg1, train, test, pred, target, IDcol, 'sub_log.csv')
```

but getting TypeError msg, shown below:
[image]

can someone please explain why its happening and how to resolve it?

Comment: `[target]` is a list, and `IDcol` is a string. You can't add a list and a string. What do you mean for it to do?

Comment: yah i know that i tried to chnage **Idcol** to list but it won't work. when i add (for eg. IDcol =['employee_id','age']) column in **IDcol** it works fine but my models f1 score drop because of extra column in **IDcol**. i want to store my prediction in target with respect of **IDcol** then store them into a csv file.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to make sense. You define `target` and `IDCol` globally a strings, but then accept variables with the same names as arguments to your `modelfit` function and try and treat them as lists. I can't tell how it is supposed to work.

Comment: i changed my code and it works fine. thank you for ur time.